# What's wrong with this solution to MSVC's double-checked locking bug and function statics?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, thread-safety

It's not entirely clear why this doesn't work. The managed object still gets constructed twice:

```
/** Returns an object with static storage duration.
    This is a workaround for Visual Studio 2013 and earlier non-thread
    safe initialization of function local objects with static storage duration.

    Usage:
    @code
    my_class& foo()
    {
        static static_initializer <my_class> instance;
        return *instance;
    }
    @endcode
*/
template <
    class T,
    class Tag = void
>
class static_initializer
{
private:
    T* instance_;

public:
    template <class... Args>
    explicit static_initializer (Args&&... args);

    T&
    get() noexcept
    {
        return *instance_;
    }

    T&
    operator*() noexcept
    {
        return get();
    }

    T*
    operator->() noexcept
    {
        return &get();
    }
};

template <class T, class Tag>
template <class... Args>
static_initializer <T, Tag>::static_initializer (Args&&... args)
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    static std::aligned_storage <sizeof(T),
        std::alignment_of <T>::value>::type storage;
    instance_ = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&storage);

    // Double checked lock:
    //  0 = unconstructed
    //  1 = constructing
    //  2 = constructed
    //
    static long volatile state; // zero-initialized
    if (state != 2)
    {
        struct destroyer
        {
            T* t_;
            destroyer (T* t) : t_(t) { }
            ~destroyer() { t_->~T(); }
        };

        for(;;)
        {
            long prev;
            prev = InterlockedCompareExchange(&state, 1, 0);
            if (prev == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    ::new(instance_) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);                   
                    static destroyer on_exit (instance_);
                    InterlockedIncrement(&state);
                }
                catch(...)
                {
                    InterlockedDecrement(&state);
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else if (prev == 1)
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            }
            else
            {
                assert(prev == 2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

#else
    static T object(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    instance_ = &object;

#endif
}
```

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(10));` what is this for?

Comment: @dyp: appears to be used as a poor way to block until the type is fully constructed.

Comment: @MooingDuck I feared so. Will fail in case of an exception.

Comment: @dyp Right, its the poor man's spin lock. This is to avoid requiring a fully constructed std::mutex (which would bring us back to the problem of function local statics not working in vs2013 and earlier).

Comment: @dyp As written, this is exception safe. Only the constructor of T can throw, and its wrapped in a try/catch - unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @VinnieFalco: You're aware that this has the limitation of one static for each type/initializer-list?

Comment: @MooingDuck Right, that's what the "Tag" template argument is for (to have multiple instances of the same T).

Comment: @dyp Right, after an exception, subsequent threads will retry the constructor (and likely throw).

Comment: You need thread-safe access `instance`, too (non-cached).

Comment: @dyp access to volatiles is an implicit memory barrier on x86 / msvc (I think)

Comment: @VinnieFalco: Why are the "globals" static to the function rather than part of the `static_initializer` itself?  Also since it's Windows specific anyways, why not `yield()` instead of sleep?

Comment: @VinnieFalco: Did you try putting a breakpoint in `T`'s constructor?  Did that reveal anything?

Comment: @MooingDuck If the "globals" are static to the class then you have the issue of order of initialization of objects at file scope with static storage duration. Having them local to the function guarantees that they will be valid on entry. I agree, yield() is probably better. I'm just in the habit of using as much stdlib as possible.

Comment: @VinnieFalco: Your code appears to depend on the function-local `static long volatile state` being initialized only once to zero, are you absolutely 100% certain that the `volatile` bypasses the bug you're trying to work around?

Comment: @MooingDuck Absolutely, zero-initialization happens when the .EXE is loaded and before any code executes. 'volatile' under msvc just means "fully fenced."

Comment: If `instance_ = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&storage);` is executed by multiple threads, you have conflicting evaluations of expressions => data race => UB. `instance_` is not `volatile`.

Comment: @dyp: I don't think so, `storage` is a global who's address is known at _compile time_.  Even if the expression is executed by multiple threads, they'll all come to the same result, and write to different `instance_` members.  It's totally fine.  (Each thread would have a different `instance_`)

Comment: @VinnieFalco: The `state` itself may be fully fenced, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the double-initialization bug isn't also affecting it.  It's really the only possible cause I see

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm arguing on a language-lawyer-level here. Don't know what the optimizer will come up with if it sees this code.

Comment: @dyp: No wait, I just realized what you're saying.  You're 100% right, that UB could be the problem as well.

Comment: Good point about multiple threads executing the assignment to `instance_` although it shouldn't be the cause of malfunction.

Comment: Random code improvement unrelated to problem: `static static_initializer <my_class> instance;` -- replace with `static auto instance = make_static<my_class>([]{}, args...);` -- you can use the type of `[]{}` as your tag (don't call it), as it will be distinct in every call.  Rework `make_static` to be `make_static<my_class>([]{})(args...)` and you can use macros to give you `auto instance = MAKE_STATIC(my_class)(args...);`.

Comment: Wait, why is `static static_initializer <my_class>` static?  I see no point, it would only make things more complex.  (I guess it means you won't evaluate the args more than once?  But now you do it an indeterminate number of times, ik.  If you want to avoid that, have the caller pass in a lambda to construct the object)

Comment: @Yakk The intent is to make the syntax resemble "regular" statics as closely as possible.

Comment: @VinnieFalco Evaluating the arguments an indeterminate number of times is not a good idea.  And it adds complexity to correctness analysis.  Get it working first.

Comment: Are you *certain* that the problem is the same object being initialized multiple times, and not multiple objects being initialized once each?

Comment: I think the problem is that under visual studio, subsequent calls to the constructor are simply skipped, so get() is called before the object is fully constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the following code is correct. It passes the unit tests. The problem with the original code is that Visual Studio 2013 and earlier protect the constructor of function-local objects with a simple bool. The bool is set to true just before the constructor is called. Therefore, other threads can see the object as fully constructed when it is not. The implementation posted in the question is incorrect, because the get() function can access the managed object before it is fully constructed.

This new implementation protects get() by spinning until the object is fully constructed. The bulk of the remaining changes revolve around making the state data available to the other member functions.

Anyone who is a version of Visual Studio that supports C++11 and is 2013 or earlier who experiences the problem of function-local statics not being thread safe can replace:

```
void example()
{
    static MyObject foo;
    foo.bar();
}
```

with

```
void example()
{
    beast::static_initializer <MyObject> foo;
    foo->bar();
}
```

And fix the problem of concurrent access to function local objects with static storage duration. The code:

```
#ifndef BEAST_UTILITY_STATIC_INITIALIZER_H_INCLUDED
#define BEAST_UTILITY_STATIC_INITIALIZER_H_INCLUDED

#include <beast/utility/noexcept.h>
#include <utility>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>
#include <intrin.h>
#endif

namespace beast {

/** Returns an object with static storage duration.
    This is a workaround for Visual Studio 2013 and earlier non-thread
    safe initialization of function local objects with static storage duration.

    Usage:
    @code
    my_class& foo()
    {
        static static_initializer <my_class> instance;
        return *instance;
    }
    @endcode
*/
#ifdef _MSC_VER
template <
    class T,
    class Tag = void
>
class static_initializer
{
private:
    struct data_t
    {
        //  0 = unconstructed
        //  1 = constructing
        //  2 = constructed
        long volatile state;

        typename std::aligned_storage <sizeof(T),
            std::alignment_of <T>::value>::type storage;
    };

    struct destroyer
    {
        T* t_;
        explicit destroyer (T* t) : t_(t) { }
        ~destroyer() { t_->~T(); }
    };

    static
    data_t&
    data() noexcept;

public:
    template <class... Args>
    explicit static_initializer (Args&&... args);

    T&
    get() noexcept;

    T&
    operator*() noexcept
    {
        return get();
    }

    T*
    operator->() noexcept
    {
        return &get();
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T, class Tag>
auto
static_initializer <T, Tag>::data() noexcept ->
    data_t&
{
    static data_t _; // zero-initialized
    return _;
}

template <class T, class Tag>
template <class... Args>
static_initializer <T, Tag>::static_initializer (Args&&... args)
{
    data_t& _(data());

    // Double Checked Locking Pattern

    if (_.state != 2)
    {
        T* const t (reinterpret_cast<T*>(&_.storage));

        for(;;)
        {
            long prev;
            prev = InterlockedCompareExchange(&_.state, 1, 0);
            if (prev == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    ::new(t) T (std::forward<Args>(args)...);                   
                    static destroyer on_exit (t);
                    InterlockedIncrement(&_.state);
                }
                catch(...)
                {
                    // Constructors that throw exceptions are unsupported
                    std::terminate();
                }
            }
            else if (prev == 1)
            {
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
            else
            {
                assert(prev == 2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T, class Tag>
T&
static_initializer <T, Tag>::get() noexcept
{
    data_t& _(data());
    for(;;)
    {
        if (_.state == 2)
            break;
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&_.storage);
}

#else
template <
    class T,
    class Tag = void
>
class static_initializer
{
private:
    T* instance_;

public:
    template <class... Args>
    explicit
    static_initializer (Args&&... args);

    T&
    get() noexcept
    {
        return *instance_;
    }

    T&
    operator*() noexcept
    {
        return get();
    }

    T*
    operator->() noexcept
    {
        return &get();
    }
};

template <class T, class Tag>
template <class... Args>
static_initializer <T, Tag>::static_initializer (Args&&... args)
{
    static T t (std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    instance_ = &t;
}

#endif

}

#endif

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <beast/utility/static_initializer.h>
#include <beast/unit_test/suite.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>

namespace beast {

static_assert(__alignof(long) >= 4, "");

class static_initializer_test : public unit_test::suite
{
public:
    // Used to create separate instances for each test
    struct cxx11_tag { };
    struct beast_tag { };
    template <std::size_t N, class Tag>
    struct Case
    {
        enum { count = N };
        typedef Tag type;
    };

    struct Counts
    {
        Counts()
            : calls (0)
            , constructed (0)
            , access (0)
        {
        }

        // number of calls to the constructor
        std::atomic <long> calls;

        // incremented after construction completes
        std::atomic <long> constructed;

        // increment when class is accessed before construction
        std::atomic <long> access;
    };

    /*  This testing singleton detects two conditions:
        1. Being accessed before getting fully constructed
        2. Getting constructed twice
    */
    template <class Tag>
    class Test;

    template <class Function>
    static
    void
    run_many (std::size_t n, Function f);

    template <class Tag>
    void
    test (cxx11_tag);

    template <class Tag>
    void
    test (beast_tag);

    template <class Tag>
    void
    test();

    void
    run ();
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class Tag>
class static_initializer_test::Test
{
public:
    explicit
    Test (Counts& counts);

    void
    operator() (Counts& counts);
};

template <class Tag>
static_initializer_test::Test<Tag>::Test (Counts& counts)
{
    ++counts.calls;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (10));
    ++counts.constructed;
}

template <class Tag>
void
static_initializer_test::Test<Tag>::operator() (Counts& counts)
{
    if (! counts.constructed)
        ++counts.access;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class Function>
void
static_initializer_test::run_many (std::size_t n, Function f)
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cond;
    std::atomic <bool> start (false);
    std::vector <std::thread> threads;

    threads.reserve (n);

    {
        std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock (mutex);
        for (auto i (n); i-- ;)
        {
            threads.emplace_back([&]()
            {
                {
                    std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock (mutex);
                    while (! start.load())
                        cond.wait(lock);
                }

                f();
            });
        }
        start.store (true);
    }
    cond.notify_all();
    for (auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();
}

template <class Tag>
void
static_initializer_test::test (cxx11_tag)
{
    testcase << "cxx11 " << Tag::count << " threads";

    Counts counts;

    run_many (Tag::count, [&]()
    {
        static Test <Tag> t (counts);
        t(counts);
    });

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    // Visual Studio 2013 and earlier can exhibit both double
    // construction, and access before construction when function
    // local statics are initialized concurrently.
    //
    expect (counts.constructed > 1 || counts.access > 0);

#else
    expect (counts.constructed == 1 && counts.access == 0);

#endif
}

template <class Tag>
void
static_initializer_test::test (beast_tag)
{
    testcase << "beast " << Tag::count << " threads";

    Counts counts;

    run_many (Tag::count, [&counts]()
    {
        static static_initializer <Test <Tag>> t (counts);
        (*t)(counts);
    });

    expect (counts.constructed == 1 && counts.access == 0);
}

template <class Tag>
void
static_initializer_test::test()
{
    test <Tag> (typename Tag::type {});
}

void
static_initializer_test::run ()
{
    test <Case<  4, cxx11_tag>> ();
    test <Case< 16, cxx11_tag>> ();
    test <Case< 64, cxx11_tag>> ();
    test <Case<256, cxx11_tag>> ();

    test <Case<  4, beast_tag>> ();
    test <Case< 16, beast_tag>> ();
    test <Case< 64, beast_tag>> ();
    test <Case<256, beast_tag>> ();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BEAST_DEFINE_TESTSUITE(static_initializer,utility,beast);

}
```

Comment: What was the bug?  How does a person encountering the problem fix the bug?  What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that while Microsoft doesn't support `magic statics` yet in VS2013, their implementation of `std::call_once` is thread safe. It may be possible to use that.

```
class Instance
{
  public:
      Instance& GetInstance() {
          std::call_once(m_Flag, [] { m_Instance.reset(new Instance); } );
          return *m_Instance.get();
      }
  private:
      static std::unique_ptr<Instance> m_Instance;
      static std::once_flag m_Flag;
      Instance(void);
};
```

Comment: This just pushes the problem elsewhere. If Instance is a global, you have the issue of order of construction of objects in different translation units. If Instance is a function local static, then you're back to the same problem.

Comment: It's lazy initialization. Instance isn't created until someone asks for it by calling `Instance::GetInstance`, since `std::call_once` only runs one time, there shouldn't be any problem with the order of construction.

Comment: m_Flag is a file-local object with static storage duration. If another translation unit calls GetInstance(), there is no guarantee that m_Flag has been constructed. This code produces undefined behavior as written.

Comment: @VinnieFalco: I don't think this is undefined behavior at the language level, it simply triggers the exact MSVC bug it's intending to bypass.

Comment: @MooingDuck m_Flag is accessed in other translation units, possibly before being constructed. The order of construction of file scoped objects with static storage duration is undefined between translation units.

Comment: @VinnieFalco: Ah, I see it.  Yes it does.  However, _that_ is trivially fixable.

Comment: @MooingDuck Sure, it's fixable...with a function local static (lol)

Comment: @VinnieFalco: Or merely accessing `m_Flag` through an accessor.